# How to remove duplicate rows in R based on condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("001", "001", "001", "002", "002", "003", "003"),
                 x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1))

 id x
001 0
001 0
001 0
002 0
002 1
003 0
003 1
```

The nature of the data is such that it is possible for some `id` to only have `x = 0` rows. In the case where `x = 1` for a given `id`, it only occurs once, and that too in the last row for that `id`. I want to remove duplicate rows for each `id`, but in case `x = 1` for an `id`, I want to keep only that row.

The desired output:

```
 id x
001 0
002 1
003 1
```

A `tidyverse` solution is preferable. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the title of my question could be edited to make it more helpful to locate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `slice_max`

```
df %>%
    slice_max(x, by = id) %>%
    distinct()
```

or (as comments from @r2evans)

```
df %>%
    slice_max(x, by = id, with_ties = FALSE)
```

which gives

```
   id x
1 001 0
2 002 1
3 003 1
```

Comment: You can use `with_ties=FALSE` for a simpler `slice_max(df, x, by = id, with_ties = FALSE)`

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the contribution! Yes, that's more concise!

Answer (score 5):

in base R you could use `aggregate` function:

```
aggregate(x ~ id, df, max)
   id x
1 001 0
2 002 1
3 003 1
```